# Flex - determine which button was clicked in Dialog

Tags: apache-flex, events, dialog

I am using browseForSave() to give the user a chance to save a file before navigating back to a previous screen. As of now the cancel button on the save dialog just closes the save dialog. I want  to see if the cancel button was clicked, and if so continue navigating back to the previous screen without saving. Right now the person has to save the file in order to move back. Below is the code I'm using.

```
public function save(e:MouseEvent):void{
            if (currentFile) {
            if (stream != null) 
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            stream = new FileStream();
            stream.openAsync(currentFile, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, writeIOErrorHandler);
            var str:String = mainTextField.text;
            str = str.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
            str = str.replace(/\n/g, File.lineEnding);
            stream.writeUTFBytes(str);
            stream.close();
            dataChanged = false;
        } 
        else
        {
            saveAs(null);
        }
        }

        private function saveAs(event:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            var fileChooser:File;
            if (currentFile)
            {
                fileChooser = currentFile;
            }
            else
            {
                fileChooser = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('untitled.html')
            }
            fileChooser.browseForSave("Save As");
            fileChooser.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveAsFileSelected);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is AIR, you could listen for the 'cancel' event. If not, I don't think you can.